# How to View Users Connected to Ad-Hoc Network on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ad-hoc-network, connection-sharing

**Question**
How do I detect/manage users who are connected to my laptop's ad-hoc network?

**Background**
I have a Windows 7 laptop with a wired network connection.  I've [set up an ad-hoc network following these instructions](http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot).  I've successfully connected my mobile devices but, to do so, I had to set the encryption to WEP (instead of WPA).  Of course, WEP is very, very easy to crack and I am in a hotel so I want to be able to monitor, at least, the number users connected to my laptop's ad-hoc WiFi network.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to view the full list of connected users and boot those who don't belong.  Better yet, I'd like to be able to limit the number of connections.  Better still, I'd like to limit those connections to particular MAC addresses.

Is any of this possible?